# 内部CSSは(htmlへ記述するから)キャッシュされないが、外部CSSはキャッシュされる？

Tags: html, css

**仕組みが分からないのですが、下記認識で合っているでしょうか？**

---

**外部CSS**
・キャッシュされる

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

---

**内部CSS**
・キャッシュされない
・HTMLはキャッシュされない？？

```
 <styles>body{font-size:100%;}</style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<style>` 要素に直接CSSを記述した場合、それもHTMLファイルの一部ですから、HTMLファイルの一部としてキャッシュされる可能性があります。キャッシュされないわけではありません。キャッシュの挙動を制御する方法として Cache-Control ヘッダなどがありますが、これはHTMLファイルに対してもCSSファイルに対しても有効です。

ブラウザのF5などでキャッシュの有効期限を無視したリクエストを行えるかという話であれば、外部リソースには影響しない場合があります。その場合はブラウザのキャッシュをクリアしたり、各外部リソースに直接アクセスして再読み込みを行う必要があるでしょう。

もっとも、それが必要になるようであれば、キャッシュの期限が即座に切れるようにHTTPヘッダで制御したり、URLにタイムスタンプやバージョンを埋め込んで確実に新しいものが読み込まれるようにすべきだとは思いますが。